# How to build Qt Creator and Qt5 from source in Qt Creator?

Tags: linux, qt, qt-creator, qmake

Getting "Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: qml" when trying to build Qt Creator.

Qt5 is built from source. I can open and build projects from it in Qt Creator.

But when opening `qtcreator.pro` and trying to build Qt Creator itself with the same kit, it gives "Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: qml". The `qtdeclarative.pro` shows similar errors, but rebuilds fine.

The `qtcreator.pro` builds fine with the Qt5.8 kit from the Qt site.

But I need to be able debug and edit all code across Qt and Qt Creator. How to build Qt source and Qt Creator source inside the Qt Creator?

Comment: How did you build Qt ?

Comment: @BenjaminT, `./configure -debug && make -j4`. It kinda works with `./configure -debug -prefix $HOME/Qt-install && make -j4 && make install`. But you then have to copy the libraries from the build dir to the install dir every time.